# Android Studio uses the first keyboard layout for shortcuts hotkeys

Tags: android-studio, ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, dvorak

I have multiple keyboard layouts defined for my OS. Two of them are English `Querty` and `Dvorak`. The problem that I have is that the shortcut keys of Android Studio, always work with the first layout, even if the second one is active. All other applications honor the selected layout and don't have this problem.

For example, I have selected the second layout which is `Dvorak`:
[image]

Now in `Android Studio` I enter <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> to undo something. But the shortcut for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> gets triggered because <kbd>Z</kbd> in Dvorak is defined in the key <kbd>/</kbd> in Querty.

Is there a way to fix this problem?

P.S: I'm using Ubuntu 19.04.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are correct that Android studio uses the first keyboard layout.

A workaround is to move the desired keyboard layout to the top of the list. In Ubuntu this is Settings -> Keyboard -> drag and drop the desired layout to the top.

Comment: This is unfortunate since I need to use different layouts for different applications, and they all depend on the first keyboard layout, but I can't make them all first.